# Is boost optimized to use variadic templates from C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, boost, clang

I can not find information on (1) whether Boost is already available in a version using variadic templates from C++11 instead of using MPL and (2) what kind of compile time reduction one might expect when making "typical" use of common Boost idioms (ptr, tuple, pair, mutex, etc.) on common platforms (MSVC 2013, clang, gcc). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[(Boost) Hana](http://ldionne.com/hana/) seems to be that initiative. Many sub-libraries opted to do their "next" versions c++11 only (Spirit, Fusion, Proto-0x and others?).

So there's a movement away from MPL if you will. I don't think MPL will be "replaced" in the near future. It does seem more likely that something like Hana would replace MPL for libraries that opt-out of c++03 support.

The compile time reductions are considerable. E.g. http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/02/23/spirit-x3-on-github/ sees considerable speed ups. You can find some ad-hoc compile-time comparisons on the [spirit-general] mailing list, if I remember correctly.